# Phaser3 time elapsed when tab loses focus

Tags: phaser-framework

i would like to know how can i determine the time that has passed between the game losing focus and getting it back again. i saw some post about it, but it was for phaser2 and doesn't seem to work with phaser3.

Is there a way to set a listener for the scene destroy, or scene pause  and resume?

I also tried to do it with setting a listener for the window it self, but still no luck.

Is there an example i can take a look at or something? Also is there a list of possible events that i can listen too somewhere? I don't find it in the docs anywhere :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: After reading through the code: 1) I hope the creator does another scene overview document in the future and 2) `document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => { console.log(document["hidden"]); });` seems to be working fairly well.